# Ошибка "The system cannot find the file specified." при попытке запустить код Go

Tags: golang, cmd, visual-studio-code

Написал код на языке Go, когда хочу запустить его через командную строку, появляется ошибка. Смотреть на картинке.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
fmt.Println("hello world")
}
```

Comment: А файл main.go точно есть в папке C:/Users/user?

Comment: в папке `C:/Users/user` нету файла main.go

Comment: Добавил файл в папку, все равно ошибка, добавил новую картинку
@SeniorPomidor

Comment: Не верно настроена рабочая дериктория

Comment: Что пишет команда `echo %GOPATH%`?

Comment: Ну так вы добавили файл в C:/Users/user/gostart. А запускаете из C:/Users/user

Comment: C:\Users\user\go @Николай

Comment: А как через командную строку запускать из C:/Users/user/gostart ? @Alpensin

Comment: @user495806 с картинками сложно работать. лучше прикладывать строки. простой копируйте из консоли и приложите к вопросу в следующий раз.  не могли бы показать содержимое файла, нажав на править и вставить содержимое туда? что-то мне кажется, что у вас в проекте есть еще один файл.

Comment: но вероятнее всего внутри вы пытаетесь читать файл, который не существует. поэтому получаете ошибку System cannot find file specified

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Я написал простейший код который выводит hello world, добавил в вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте статью https://habr.com/ru/post/249545/ там есть для вас полезная информация.
Проект должен лежать по определенному пути, плюс запускать надо из того места, где у вас лежит main.go - `C:/Users/user/gostart`

Comment: к сожалению, это не ответ на вопрос. когда у вас будет [определенный уровень репутации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) вы сможете оставлять комментарии